# How to read a single column CSV file in bash?

Tags: bash, csv

I am relatively new to bash/programming in general.

I have a single column CSV that looks like this:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain4.com
```

I want to run through each entry and do something with it.  Here is my code:

```
foo(){
i=0
  while read -a line; 
    do
      echo ${line[i]}
      ((i++))
    done < myfile.csv 
}
```

And nothing happens.  I have figured out that if I change the file I'm pointing at to:

```
done< <(grep '' myfile.csv)
```

it will work, but only spit out the very last line of the CSV, like this:

```
domain4.com
```

Again, I am a beginner and teaching myself this stuff, so any explanations you want to give with your answers would be GREATLY appreciated!

**EDIT** So it appears that my new problem is removing the ^M character from my CSV file.  Once I figure out how to do this, I will mark the answer here that works for me.

Comment: If there is only one column then `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < file.csv` would also work.

Comment: same result: nothing...

Comment: Can you show output of `head file.csv | cat -vte`

Comment: I realize you are asking for Bash advice, but other Linux tools might be better suited for working with text files line by line. I would suggest to give a try to `awk`

Comment: @anubhava, here is the output: domain1.com^Mdomain2.com^Mdomain3.com^Mdomain4.com

Comment: Try: `while read -d $'\r' -r line; do echo "$line"; done < file.csv`

Comment: @anubhava hey, that works, except it doesn't read the very last line...

Comment: also, @jakegould, is there a prohibition on thanking people?  confused by your edit.

Comment: @anubhava: that returns nothing

Comment: ok try: `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(tr '\r' '\n' < file.csv)`

Comment: @anubhava: that returns the same results as your first suggestion... all but the last entry

Comment: Try `echo >> file.csv` **before** you run my suggested `while` loop.

Comment: that worked!  I would thank you but it's _strictly prohibited_

Comment: ok I will post it as an answer so that other users might get help in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 issues:

1. Your lines are all ending with `\r`
2. There is no new line or `\r` at the end of last line

To fix this issue use this script:

```
echo >> file.csv
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(tr '\r' '\n' < file.csv)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store your lines on an array you'd simply do:

```
readarray -t lines < file
```

And, if you want to try processing those lines you can have something like

```
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Or by index (mind `!`):

```
for i in "${!lines[@]}"; do
    echo "${lines[i]}"
done
```

Indices start with 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read p; do
  echo $p
done < myfile.csv
```

Comment: This example does answer the question for the limited data set shown in the example, but would fail if there are spaces in the text.  You might want to prefix this with `IFS=$'\n'`

Comment: @KirkRoybal While youre right, need to add than the example data showings domain names and domain names can't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply read the file into the array with:

```
array=( `<file` )
```

If you have need to use numerical indexes, then you can access the elements with:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++))
    printf " array [%2d]: %s\n" "$i" "${array[$i]}"
done
```